# How to include files in dynamic pages in PHP?

Tags: php

So, I want to include `head.php` in my `threads.php` page. Both of these files are in the same root directory of the project.

And threads.php is a dynamic page that creates page for every topic and display all threads related to it. Like if i want to access threads related to PHP topic, so the URL of it will be threads.php/?thread=PHP

But if I am including it like:

```
<?php include('head.php'); ?>
```

It is not loading the page because the directory it is loading is `threads.php/images`

So, I tried to move one directory up to solve this, and did this:

```
<?php include('../head.php'); ?>
```

But it is also giving error:

> include(../head.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\corephpforum\threads.php

Then I did this:

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'head.php'); ?>
```

But still same error:

> include(C:/xampp/htdocshead.php): failed to open stream:

How to solve this?

Edit:

This is the current directory of my project:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\corephpforum
```

and both of the files are here.

threads.php is creating URL like:

```
http://localhost/corephpforum/threads.php/?thread=PHP
```

But for the bootstrap css file that is in css folder of this directory, it is showing as:

http://localhost/corephpforum/threads.php/css/bootstrap.css

Question of my is why it is including threads.php in it???

I also include bootstrap and head.php in my index.php, login.php and register.php. But there it was working perfectly fine. But as threads.php is creating URL dynamically that's why i think it is showing this error.

SOVLED..

The problem was with the URL:

```
http://localhost/corephpforum/threads.php/?thread=PHP
```

/ before ?thread was what creating problem. I removed it and it is working fine.

Comment: Where is `head.php`, and where is `threads.php`? Is `threads.php` the one being accessed or is another file including it?

Comment: update your question and put the project directory for us to better understand

Comment: @pepperjack the are in the same root folder of the project.

Comment: If in same folder then <?php include('head.php'); ?> must work.

Comment: What do you mean by "It is not loading the page because the directory it is loading is threads.php/images" does it include the .php or not? This question is too vague. Please explain why the first thing doesn't work (as it should be perfectly fine from what you have told us so far.)

Comment: @pepperjack It means that it is including threads.php in its path rather than just simply use /images folder without including threads.php

Comment: Is `C:/xampp/htdocs` the folder location for `threads.php`? Because then your error says `include(C:/xampp/htdocshead.php):` simply because you forgot the `/` between htdocs and head.php, like so: `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/head.php');`

Comment: @pepperjack name of the project is 'corephpforum'. So, it is in C:/xampp/htdocs/corephpforum/ directory. And head.php is also in the same directory.

Comment: Have you tried `<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/corephpforum/head.php'); ?>` then?

Comment: @pepperjack Now it is showing this directory: http://localhost/corephpforum/threads.php/images/php.jpg

Why it including threads.php everywhere?? Please check question again, i has added more information to it.

Comment: `<?php include __DIR__ . '/folder/my_file.php'; ?>`

Comment: @DarkBee Still same error.

Comment: You have 2 errors. The include which doesn't work. It should work with `include ( 'head.php' ); or include ( __DIR__ '/head.php' );` The problem with your images, is that you need to add the correct URL. I think you have: `images/filename.jpg`. but try: `/corephpforum/images/filename.jpg` But without any code, we can't really help you.

Comment: Please post the complete code of this page or a MCVE. I'm wondering if you are doing something else wrong.